# PHP Session lost with different client ip

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a strange behaviour of sessions in PHP when I connect my client through a balanced gateway with two ip addresses to my hosting server.

I correctly initialize a session with a cookie, I set a session boolean variable and for debug I print this informations:

```
    echo var_dump($_SESSION["islogged"]);
    echo var_dump(session_id());
    echo var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Than I refresh many times the page and I get two results:

```
bool(false) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "48.129.84.146" 
bool(true) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "96.19.184.38" 
bool(true) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "96.19.184.38" 
bool(false) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "48.129.84.146" 
bool(false) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "48.129.84.146" 
bool(true) string(26) "ism1vg1de6v0b1r8b2ng337uh3" string(13) "96.19.184.38" 
...
```

Ad you can see the session is the same, however the session bar changes.
Do you know how to solve this?

This is the login check:

```
$ISLOGGED=!empty($_SESSION["islogged"])
```

And this is the logon code:

```
$ISLOGGED=$_SESSION["islogged"]=$_POST["password"]==$password;
```

Comment: Weird. Do you have some more code. It could be somewhere else.

Comment: Php has somethint like "safe_mode" or something like this that checks client's ip?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're using suhosin that does extra session mangling using the remote IP address.  You may want to double-check [cryptraddr and checkraddr](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.cookie.cryptraddr) values in your configuration.

Comment: I will ask the hoster. Thank you